# Get the data between two dates from two fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date

I m calling GET API by passing start date (2022-05-01) and end date (2022-05-31) to get emp list which is appears between this two date from mongodb. Below is the object in mongodb.

```
{
    "emp_list" : [
        "114",
        "118"
    ],
    "pattern_code" : 15,
    "effct_bgn_dt" : ISODate("2022-04-01T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "effct_end_dt" : ISODate("2022-05-31T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "source" : "ASSIGN_SHIFT",
},

{
    "emp_list" : [
        "117",
        "115"
    ],
    "pattern_code" : 30,
    "effct_bgn_dt" : ISODate("2022-05-01T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "effct_end_dt" : ISODate("2022-05-31T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "source" : "ASSIGN_SHIFT",
}



{
    "emp_list" : [
        "233",
        "400"
    ],
    "pattern_code" : 30,
    "effct_bgn_dt" : ISODate("2022-08-01T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "effct_end_dt" : ISODate("2022-10-31T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "source" : "ASSIGN_SHIFT",
},
```

From above object, My expected output is first and second object i.e [114,118,117,115] why because this two objects appears between the above two date.

Comment: Please show us your query.

Comment: db.employeeWiseShiftPattern.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
            {
                
                $or: 
                [
                    { effct_bgn_dt: { $gte: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30"), $lte: ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30") }},
                    { effct_end_dt: { $lte: ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30"), $gte: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30") }}
                ] 
                        
                   
            }
    }
])

Comment: Please edit your question for additional information, instead of putting it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken then it would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $and: [
              { $gte: [ "$effct_bgn_dt", ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30") ] },
              { $lte: [ "$effct_bgn_dt", ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30") ] }
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              { $lte: [ "effct_end_dt", ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30") ] },
              { $gte: [ "effct_end_dt", ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30") ] }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M8gltAxMSdu)

Or use "find":

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      effct_bgn_dt: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30"),
        $lte: ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30")
      }
    },
    {
      effct_end_dt: {
        $lte: ISODate("2022-05-30T00:30:00.000+05:30"),
        $gte: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:30:00.000+05:30")
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: {
 "message" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue",
 "name" : "MongoError"
}   -  im getting this issue when i run above query

Comment: Which version of MongoDB do you use? As you can see in the playground, the query should work.

Comment: we are using Mongodb (3.4)

Comment: [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/query/expr/): *New in version 3.6*